# Double Render Error with simple controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, activerecord, render

I'm getting a weird error in my api rails app:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Api::V1::AdsController#restaurant
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

I found this page https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html about double rendering, but I don't really get what they mean and how it applies to my situation.

I have this in my controller:

```
class Api::V1::AdsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :set_ad, only: [ :show ]

  def index
    @ads = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Restaurantes").ads)
  end

  def restaurant
    @restaurants = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Restaurantes").ads)
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_ad
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    authorize @ad
  end
end
```

And this in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :ads, only: [ :index, :show ] do
        collection do
          get 'restaurant', to: 'ads#restaurant'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

And I have 3 views: 
index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.array! @ads do |ad|
  json.extract! ad,
  :id,
  :empresa,
  :direccion_principal,
  :tel,
  :email_principal,
  :web,
  :facebook,
  :instagram,
  :twitter,
  :isla
end
```

restaurant.json.jbuilder = the same as index

show.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! @ad, :id, :empresa, :direccion_principal
```

Can someone see the problem here?

EDIT:

AdPolicy:

```
class AdPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def show?
    true
  end
end
```

Base Controller:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index

  rescue_from StandardError,                with: :internal_server_error
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError,   with: :user_not_authorized
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  private

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    render json: {
      error: "Unauthorized #{exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore.camelize}.#{exception.query}"
    }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def not_found(exception)
    render json: { error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
  end

  def internal_server_error(exception)
    if Rails.env.development?
      response = { type: exception.class.to_s, message: exception.message, backtrace: exception.backtrace }
    else
      response = { error: "Internal Server Error" }
    end
    render json: response, status: :internal_server_error
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `policy_scope` method? And do you have any `before_action`s in your `BaseController`?

Comment: @GavinMiller I added the 2 things you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. It had to do with the BaseController. I forgot to add :restaurant to the after_action :verify_authorized and verify_policy_scoped. With the BaseController below it works now.

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :restaurant]
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index, :restaurant, :beach_restaurant, :cafe]

  rescue_from StandardError,                with: :internal_server_error
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError,   with: :user_not_authorized
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  private

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    render json: {
      error: "Unauthorized #{exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore.camelize}.#{exception.query}"
    }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def not_found(exception)
    render json: { error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
  end

  def internal_server_error(exception)
    if Rails.env.development?
      response = { type: exception.class.to_s, message: exception.message, backtrace: exception.backtrace }
    else
      response = { error: "Internal Server Error" }
    end
    render json: response, status: :internal_server_error
  end
end
```